# Add space to the previously assigned ubuntu

Tags: 10.04, partitioning, gparted, disk-usage

When I installed Ubuntu with Windows XP I put in a partition of 12 GB and if the installation asked me to assign a space not because I put half (6 GB) and now I want to raise it and have read by HAI to be using Gparted I personally do not like using xD so here a picture of my partitions and so I say to do:
**Sorry for my english xD**

http://subir-imagenes.es/images/gparteljl.png

http://fotos.subefotos.com/a2ad5553fad135e3d9fb6170622c5392o.png

How do I add more space?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have a partition for ubuntu, then simply use Gparted from the ubuntu software center, it's very easy to work with.
If you don't have ubuntu in a partition then you have the same problem as me and I'm also searching for a solution.

Comment: yes my ubuntu is in a partiton, in the images you can see the gparted, but how use the program?,I tried a move the size but does not work. Other solution?